# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**My _header.html.erb is**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "Database Management", root_path, id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            SelectTable <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% if $l == 1 %>
              <% for items in @selectedtable %>    
                <li><%= link_to items, currenttable_path %> </li> 
                    <% $gh = item %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %> 
            </ul>


            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            SelectDatabase <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% for item in @selecteddatabase %>  
              <li><%= link_to item, currentdatabase_path %></li> 
                  <% $gy = item %>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
            <li><%= link_to "NewTable", newtable_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "NewDatabase", newdatabase_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "DeleteTable", deletetable_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "DeleteDatabase", deletedatabase_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Connect", connect_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Disconnect", disconnect_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Administration", administration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Quit", quit_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
</header>
```

**application_controller.rb is**

```
require 'mysql2'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  $con = Mysql2::Client.new(host: "localhost", username: "root", password: "new_password", database: "mysql")
  def header
    rs = $con.query("SHOW databases")
    i = 0 
    for y in rs
    i = i + 1
    end
    c = 0
    @selecteddatabase = Array.new(i)
    for item in rs 
      @selecteddatabase[c] = item
      c = c + 1
    end

    if $l == 1
      ts = $con.query("SHOW tables")
      i = 0 
      for y in ts
        i = i + 1
      end
      k = 0 
      @selectedtable = Array.new(i)
      for items in ts do 
        @selectedtable[k] = items 
        k = k + 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**application.html.erb is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                           'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>

  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Error is**

> NoMethodError in StatisPages#home
>
> Showing
>   /home/tamal/rails_project/DatabaseManagement_app/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb
>   where line #25 raised:
>
> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #25):
>
> 23 24 25 26 27 28
>
> <% for item in @selecteddatabase %>
>
> <%= link_to item, currentdatabase_path %>
>
> <% $gy = item %> <%
>   end %>
>
> Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>
> Rails.root: /home/tamal/rails_project/DatabaseManagement_app
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:25:in
>   `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___324107568__651057508'
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in`
>   _app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__249465561_90094870'
>
> Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller method `header` will only be called when your application receives a request that routes to it. However, since you're rendering your _header.html.erb partial in your application layout, it will be included with *every* request. You are liable to get a `NoMethodError` every time you refer to `@selecteddatabase` or `@selectedtable` when the `header` method wasn't called.

If you want the header to work as it is, you need those variables to be defined for *every* request. One way to do this would be to use `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # other stuff...

  before_filter :assign_header_variables

  def assign_header_variables
    # content of your original header method
    # ...
  end

  # more stuff...
```

I renamed the method so it wouldn't look like a controller action.

---

Original answer (that missed the bigger picture):

`@selectedtable` is assigned conditionally, specifically when `$l == 1`. You will get this error every time that `$l` isn't 1.

Comment: Why Does "SelectDatabase" when clicked do not show the dropdown menu.

Comment: If your original problem is solved and you're having a new, unrelated problem, you should ask a new question.